# jpackage post installation scripting guide

Tags: jpackage

The jpackage [user's guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/jpackage/packaging-tool-user-guide.pdf) states that script files can be run after an installation, but it doesn't provide details of what this scripting language is. Does anyone have a link(s) to detailed information?

Comment: For Linux, [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62534/adding-post-deb-install-scripts) indicates it would be a normal shell script. I would guess the same is true for macOS. That documentation says nothing about potential post-install scripts for Windows, but the one script it does mention for Windows says its extension is `wsf` (i.e., "Windows Script File").

Comment: Slaw - Thanks for your reply. Yes - looks like .sh for Linux/Mac and .wsf for Windows.